# What is the book that Denzel Washington is talking about in The Equalizer?

Tags: reference, the-equalizer

In the movie The Equalizer (2014), there is the following conversation:

> Teri: What's your book about?
>
> Robert McCall: It's about a guy who is a knight in shining armor, except he lives in a world where knights don't exist anymore.

Does anyone know what the book is that Denzel Washington (Robert McCall) is talking about?

Is it even about a real book or is this just a line for the movie?

Notes: Also in the movie, he makes a reference to Moby Dick which leads me to believe that this line is also about a real book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's don't think it's explicit in the movie but it's [**Don Quixote**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote)

The script varies slightly from the actual dialogue but it is clear....

The [**script**](https://wikileaks.org/sony/docs/03_03/Mktrsch/F%20I%20L%20M%20S/EQUALIZER/Equalizer%2020120625.pdf) has it as:

> ```
>           McCall holds up DON QUIXOTE.
>
>
>                    MCCALL
>        Guy who thinks he’s a Knight. Only
>        he lives in a world where knights
>        don’t exist any more.
> ```

Comment: I think the obvious thing is that the viewer sees McCall (as does perhaps McCall himself also does) as the two literary characters -- The Old Man and Quixote mentioned. The hooker without being familiar with the works gets in a dig indicating that she, too, understood this.